# Scala Guice pass parameter

Tags: scala, guice

I have the following Guice binding:

```
val profile = "dev";
bind[DbClient].annotatedWith(Names.named("postgres")).to[PostgresClient].in[Singleton]
```

I'd like to pass `profile` as a parameter to `PostgresClient` instance. Please advice 
 how it can be achieved with Guice and Scala.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with `@Provides` (described here: https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ProvidesMethods)

And construct your DbClient manually

```
  @Provides
  @Singleton
  @Named("postgres")
  def provideDbClient(): DbClient = {
    new PostgresClient("dev")
  }
```

I haven't tried `@Singleton` - but the rest we us frequently.